# Flutter android studio dart file is showing some weird resource data

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Login Screen]

Hi guys, I am getting this weird data inside the dart file. I had coded the screen but now it is not showing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The data which you have shown in the file is not related to dart .Its looks like some xml lines .

You mentioned that you have created the screen before so may be there been a chance that your file beign overwritten by plugin or something .

The way which you can get your original data is that if youre using git then  check the previous commit where you have the succesfully executed your dart file from there you can copy the code and you can continue with your developement .

if your not using git then the only way is re-write the code

Comment: Hey I just checked the files..It seems an error with android studio as the file is opening correctly in notepad.. May be its and android studio bug. I will check with VS code once again

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured out that it was problem regarding android studio. I tried to open the same code in VS code and notepad and it was opening. The only way to get the original file back is open the file in note pad and then copy the code and paste it back in android studio file. The code will work even if you leave the file like that. So I will file an issue in the android studio page if possible.

Comment: I too face similar issue, did you file an issue?